# Accessing data from NSJSONSerialization from different view controllers

Tags: iphone, ios, json, uiviewcontroller, nsmutablearray

I am back again and this will be my second question of the day.

Anyways, I am using `NSJSONSerialization` to parse a data from my website. The data is in array format so I am using `NSMutableArray`. The problem is, I can't access the data stored in `NSMutableArray` from different view controllers.

FirstView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *firstViewControllerArray;

@end
```

FirstView.m

```
- (void)ViewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://j4hm.t15.org/ios/jsonnews.php"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
            self.firstViewControllerArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
    }];

    [self loadArray];
}

- (void)loadArray
{
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self firstViewControllerArray]];

    //I also tried codes below, but it still won't work.
    //[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[self firstViewControllerArray]];
    //[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.firstViewControllerArray mutableCopy]];

    NSLog(@"First: %@",array);

    SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    [secondViewController setSecondViewControllerArray:array];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Second.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *secondViewControllerArray;

@end
```

Second.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"Second: %@", [self secondViewControllerArray]);
}
```

**Output**

The `NSLog(@"First: %@",array);` will output the array hence it won't be passing the SecondViewController a `(null)` value of the array.

However, `NSLog(@"Second: %@", [self secondViewControllerArray]);` will output `(null)`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe your download is completing before you push your new view controller onto the stack, and also set that view controller's array property.  Right now, you're calling -loadArray right after you tell NSURLConnection to download data asynchronously.  This download is going to finish long after you try to access the array property.

Try move the call to -loadArray within the asynchronous completion block (as seen below).  Since this block is called when the download completes, you should have your data when you push the second view controller.

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        self.firstViewControllerArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            [self loadArray];

        });
}];
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried to call loadArray inside sendAsynchronousRequest: but the result is the same, `(null)`.

Comment: Are you sure your JSON data is correct?  Try see if there is any error, and also see what the data is in string form.

Comment: Yes. The JSON data looks like this, http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://j4hm.t15.org/ios/jsonnews.php - and this is what it looks in the log of my Xcode: http://pastebin.com/BAfYHhDb

Comment: I just tried running it with the code you provided.  I updated my answer with a call to the main queue within the completion block as the completion block so the push will be done instantly, but even without that, it worked fine.  Really not sure why it's null in the second view controller now.